# Make phone calls at regular interval of time using timer?

Tags: android, timertask

I am not able to make a call using the telephone manager inside the timer (scheduleAtFixedRate)
in android. I am getting error like you cannot create handler inside the timer.

Is there any other method to make calls at regular interval of time.

Comment: if possible, share your code that you done...

Comment: see my answer!!! may it help you!

Comment: It will be doable by AlarmManager and Service . I almost do this. After some time I will give this

Comment: I have posted solved answer, try this and then please accept answer with +1 , because I have given lots of effort for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do this step by step manner

in your `AndroidManifest.XML` write this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

After that create a background Service which will call the phone everyday after 24 hours

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mp; 
    @Override   
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override   
    public void onCreate() 
    {   
      super.onCreate(); 


    }

    @Override   
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {   


        String num="98XXXX51";

        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        startActivity(in);


        return 0;

    }

    @Override   
    public void onDestroy() 
    {   
        mp.release();       
        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

For this again paste the in `AndroidManifest.xml` within `application` tag

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

After that call the service from activity

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button play, stop;

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playId);      
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopId);      
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            Intent name = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MyService.class);          
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, name, 0);//.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // Start every 30 seconds
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
            //alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));

        }

        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

          public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent name = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MyService.class);

        stopService(name);

        }

        });

    }

}
```

I give you all tested sources except xml layout.

Comment: Was helpful Thank you